How to exclude a folder from `find`?
In a MacOS terminal I am trying to find files with the find command and to exclude the folder .Spotlight-V100/ .
I tried
find . -name .Spotlight-V100/ -prune -o -type f

and
find . -path .Spotlight-V100/ -prune -o -type f

and
find .  -type f -not -path ".Spotlight-V100/"

but in all cases the find command lists files from inside the folder .Spotlight-V100/.
How to fix this command so the find command does not include and files in the folder and subfolders of the folder .Spotlight-V100/?
I also tried to remove that complete folder, but MacOS immediately recreates this folder for unknown reasons ...

In the first command, the name of the directory you want to prune is just '.Spotlight-V100' (without the trailing slash):
find . -name .Spotlight-V100 -prune -o -type f

